# Python to Javascript via JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm trying to send int data from Python to Javascript. I'd like to use input from python to control elements in Javascript. I'm just having trouble getting data sent from Python's JSON to Javascript. Below are my attempts with little luck, Python code works excellent, how to I get Javascript to read and turn that data into a variable?

Thanks in Advance! :)

```
import json
    
    x = 1
    
    while True:
    
        x = int(input())
    
        if 10 <= x <= 900:
            x += 100
    
            print(x)
    
            json.dumps(x)
```

Javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("page").style.fontWeight = json.dumps(x);

    </script>
```

Comment: It is unclear to me how you expect all of this to work. Note, `json.dumps(x)` creates a `str` object, which you never capture, and gets discarded immediately...

Comment: How do you intend to make your Python code actually communicate with your JavaScript? You haven't specified that here, you're just outputting JSON to standard output. Are you running a server in Python or JS? What is the context for this?

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? It feels like a lot is missing here. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].